# Why is a red laser pointer an example of a poor black body radiator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, laser, thermal-radiation

Is it because the laser pen only gives out infrared radiation and not emitting all wavelengths of light? I was so trouble why the red laser pointer would be an example of a poor black body radiator.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, a red laser pointer is a bad example of a black body, here is why:

A black body spectrum is generated by a *hot object*, like a piece of red-hot metal from a furnace. A solid state laser diode does not generate light by being hot, it generates light by getting electrons pushed across a semiconductor junction. The wavelength of light from such a device is fairly precisely set by the characteristics of the junction and is nearly *monochromatic*: it consists of only one wavelength of light, instead of a spread-out spectrum (like a black body) consisting of many, many different wavelengths.